# will the jquery.jplayer render the videos from akamai

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer, aem, akamai

Currently Im using **jquery.jplayer** with which Im able to play the videos which are in my local machine.Will this js be able to render the videos from **akamai** server or do we need any script change for that.I will not be able to test that locally with the akamai server, so just want to check on that.

Thanks,
Balaji.

Comment: What is the connection with Adobe CQ5?  That is, why is this question tagged with CQ5?

Comment: Hi David, generally we prefer akamai server rathan than playing videos from content dam right, so I thought that some one from cq5 might have already integrated the akamai server with the jplayer plugin, hence I tagged this question with CQ5.